# Configuring Kafka connect Postgress Debezium CDC plugin

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am trying to use kafka connect to read changes in postgress DB.
I have Kafka running on my local system and i want to use the Kafka connect API in standalone mode to read the postgress server DB changes.

```
connect-standalone.sh connect-standalone.properties dbezium.properties
```

i would appreciate if someone can help me with setting up configuration properties for CDC postgress debezium connector

https://www.confluent.io/connector/debezium-postgresql-cdc-connector/

I am following the below to construct the properties

https://debezium.io/docs/connectors/postgresql/#how-the-postgresql-connector-works

> The name of the Kafka topics takes by default the form
>   serverName.schemaName.tableName, where serverName is the logical name
>   of the connector as specified with the database.server.name
>   configuration property

and here is what i have come up with for dbezium.properties

```
name=cdc_demo
connector.class=io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector
tasks.max=1
plugin.name=wal2json
slot.name=debezium
slot.drop_on_stop=false
database.hostname=localhost
database.port=5432
database.user=postgress
database.password=postgress
database.dbname=test
time.precision.mode=adaptive
database.sslmode=disable
```

Lets say i create a PG schema name as demo and table name as suppliers

So i need to create a topic with name as **test.demo.suppliers** so that this plugin can push the data to?

Also can someone suggest a docker image which has the postgress server + with suitable replication plugin such as wal2json etc? i am having hard time configuring postgress and the CDC plugin myself.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [the tutorial](https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples/tree/master/tutorial#using-postgres) with associated [Docker Compose](https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples/blob/master/tutorial/docker-compose-postgres.yaml) and [sample config](https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples/blob/master/tutorial/register-postgres.json).

The topic you've come up with sounds correct, but if you have your Kafka broker configured to auto-create topics (which is the default behaviour IIRC) then it will get created for you and you don't need to pre-create it.